# How to store bytes of file and later create that file again?

Tags: java, android, file

So basically, I'm creating an android app where I'm storing the contents of a file in a server node. By using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to get the byte-content of a selected file like this:

```
static byte[] convertToBytes(Object object) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)) {
        out.writeObject(object);
        return bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The object parameter is where the file is going to passed down. Getting the file is a simple process by creating an intent and getting the data from the `onActivityResult()` function.

Now for example this is the (compressed, true length is over 15,000) byte array of a file:

`[120, -100, 91, -13, -106, -127, -75, -72, -120, -127, 39, 43, -79, 44, 81, 47, 51, 95, -49, 45, 51, 39, -107, 69, 119, -119, 43, 31, -17, -109, -1, -52, 12, -116, 62, 12, 44, 5, -119, 37, 25, 37, 12, 66, 62, 32, 21, -6, 57, -119, 121, -23, -6, -63, 37, 69, -103, 121, -23, -42, 21, 5, 37, 12, -22, -6, 41, -7, -55, -91, -71, -87, 121, 37, -6, 46, -82, 78, 70, -70, -122, 46, 6, -82, 86, 5, -119, -107, 32, 17, -35, -94, -44, -28, -44, -52, -126, 18, -67, -126, -108, -76, 114, 38, 6, -3, 10, 0, 122, -76, 35, 82]`

I even have a function to convert this set of bytes to a file object, like this:

```
static Object convertFromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
    try (ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
         ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis)) {
        return in.readObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

> My question is how to open that file in the android device. Will I
>   have to download the file, store it in the device internally and then
>   open it? Or can I open it just like that from my app memory or my
>   server. If not, is there a better way to get the raw contents of a
>   file, and then have a method to create a new file in another phone device
>   by using only those raw contents?

If anybody wants any clarification they can say to me and I will do my best to post as much information as I can. Thanks in advance!

**Clarification:** My file-to-byte compression and byte-to-file compression functions work correctly and that is not the problem. The problem is about using those bytes and having the ability to use them to create the same files in other devices.

Comment: Your data are on the Server as a ByteArray, you can have the Server Display the data in a webview, you can download the data and use them on your device or you can use your app to download the data and Display them inside your app.

Comment: I want to open the file with the default app of the device and not just show them. That's how I understood you :) But how can I show the file inside my app, as I don't want to show the data but to open the file(already remarked) ?

Comment: @DominikWuttke By the way I already have the data. And have even converted it to java.io.file object.

Comment: When you have the file object you can save it on your device with a filestreamwriter and use an intent to let Android decide which app can open this sort of file.

Comment: Can you please post the code or give me a link where I can find such a function? Would be great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this link you can read everything About accessing files, read and write.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#java

this is an example from the link on how to write into a file

```
String filename = "myfile";
String fileContents = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
    outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputStream.write(fileContents.getBytes());
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The File is stored where you save it, you have to define a path, but you can save it in an internal storage which is only accessible by your app.

Comment: Does it not work anymore, or why do you unaccept it?

Comment: What you are Looking for is Files.readAllBytes() to get a bytearray out of a File.

Comment: Point 2 in this Link should solve your Problem https://howtodoinjava.com/java/io/how-to-read-file-content-into-byte-array-in-java/

Comment: Hey, look at me. I just created a project because of this. Thank you very much :)